# Interpreting the vector form of the section formula

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d

To find the ratio in which B divides AC for $$A=(1,2,3)\\B=(3,4',7)\\C=(-3,-2,-5)$$
I used the section formula assuming the following format, where $\lambda:1$ is only the ratio of division; [image]

You end up with $\lambda=-3$ , which I interpreted to mean 'B lies on the other side of C at thrice the distance to C as to A'. This is quite obviously nonsense.

Trying again, I solved it by taking $\lambda:1$ to be the ratio in which B divides AC(with $\lambda$ and 1 interchanged in the diagram). Now I got $\lambda=\frac{-1}{3}$. This time, it makes sense; B lies on the other end of A. This is how it actually works out; I graphed it on GeoGebra.

Why did my first interpretation fail? I did think subsequently of interpreting it like; $$\lambda=-3= \frac 3 {-1}$$ so that $\lambda$ is effectively 3. You get the correct answer like this; B is at thrice the distance to C(in the same as initially assumed direction) as to A, and it's in the negative direction to A as compared to the initial assumption. But this doesn't seem rigouous; I had set the ratio as $\lambda:1$, and I have to interpret $\lambda$ as it is, or the 1 will be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that in actuality,
[image]$$\vec{BC}=-3\vec{AB}.$$
$$$$
Therefore, in your original setup,
[image]
$$\lambda\,\vec v =-3(1\vec{v})\\ \lambda=-3;$$
whereas in your alternative setup,
[image]
$$1\,\vec v =-3(\lambda\vec{v})\\ \lambda=-\frac13.$$

Comment: I see. So the ratio in the section formula when dealing with vectors is actually the ratio of the two vectors with endpoints at the three points, taken in any one direction, is it? And what I did wrong was taking the ratio of both the vectors with endpoints at B? I know vector division isn't really defined, but I think you'll get what I meant.

Comment: @HarryHolmes I've never heard of the section formula, but I feel that you did nothing wrong: the issue is interpreting the meaning of $\lambda'$s value in your respective *tentative* setups: in them, I used vector notation merely to reflect that fact that the points $A,B,C$, in actuality, need not be ordered alphabetically (indeed, it turns out that they aren't).

Comment: [This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_formula#In_vectors) is the section formula I meant. Also I didn't mean there was anything special about the alphabetical order, haha. I meant the sign of $\lambda$ here; it seems to depend on the vectors $\vec AB$ and $\vec BC$. I took the 1 and $\lambda$ to describe the signs of vectors $\vec AB$ and $\vec CB$.  Hope I'm clearer now.

Comment: @HarryHolmes Yep I understood what you were doing, and was just presenting it a little more rigorously/clearly.  Good questions, btw.

Comment: Right, got it, thanks.